# If $y=(x^{2}-a)(2x+b)^{3}$ decreasing on $-1<x<\frac{2}{5}$, then what is the value of $ab$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If the function $y=(x^{2}-a)(2x+b)^{3}$ decreases on the interval $-1<x<\frac{2}{5}$. Find the value of $ab$.

My attempt was first to differentiate $y$, it turns out that $y'=2(2x+b)^2(5x^{2}+bx-3a)$.

Since we want $y$ to be decreasing I let $y'<0$ then solve the inequality to get $x<-\frac{b}{2}$ and $\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^{2}+60a}}{10}<x$. This inequality implies that $\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^{2}+60a}}{10}<x<-\frac{b}{2}$.

So, by the inequality from the question and above I got $ab=-\frac{116}{75}$.

Is this correct or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you solved that inequality? how did you decide $ x <  - b/2$?

Comment: Your derivative does not look correct. Also, using Desmos it appears there are multiple solutions. Is this strictly decreasing, or can it also be non-increasing?

Comment: @CalvinLin I got it from setting $2(2x+b)^{2}(5x^{2}+bx-3a)<0$ then $(2x+b)<0$ and $5x^{2}+bx-3a>0$

Comment: @JAB $(2x+b)^2$ is never negative... What you really get is that $5x^2+bx-3a \leq 0$

Comment: @JAB That's not how inequalities work. Please review that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:
$$y=(x^{2}-a)(2x+b)^{3}\\
\text{Differentiating both side w.r.t $x$,}\\
y'=2(2x+b)^2(5x^{2}+bx-3a)\\
$$

Consider, $x=-1$ and $x=\frac{2}5$ as extreme points of the function.

$$2(-2+b)^2(5-b-3a)=0\implies 3a+b=5 \quad(\text{ for, } b\ne2)\tag{i}$$

And,
$$2\left(\frac{4}5+b\right)^2\left(\frac{4}5+\frac{2b}5-3a\right)=0\implies 15a-2b=4 \tag{ii} \quad(\text{ for, } b\ne \frac{4}5)$$
Solving (i) and (ii), $$a = \frac{2}{3}, b = 3$$

Therfore, $ab=2$

This is only one valid solution of the question.

[image: Graphical varification]

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=5x^{2}+bx-3a$. In order for $y$ to be decreasing $f(x)$ must satisfy $f(x)\le0$ for $\forall x\in[-1,\frac25]$. So
$$ f(-1)\le0,f(0)\le0,f(\frac25)\le0$$
or
$$ 5-b-3a\le0, -3a\le0,\frac45+\frac25b-3a\le0. $$
This gives
$$ a=\frac23,b=3$$
or
$$a>\frac{2}{3}, 5-3 a\leq b\leq \frac{1}{2} (15 a-4).$$
In the first case $ab=2$ and in the second case $ab$ can't be determined.